# Spring Data : relationships between 2 different data sources

Tags: spring, spring-data

In a Spring Boot Application project, I have 2 data sources:

- a MySQL database (aka "db1")
- a MongoDB database (aka "db2")

I'm using **Spring Data JPA** and **Spring Data MongoDB**, and it's working great... one at a time.

Saying db1 handles "Players", and db2 handles "Teams" (with a list of players' ID). Is it possible to make the relationship between those 2 heterogeneous entities working? (i.e. @ManyToOne, @Transactional, Lazy/Eager, etc.)

For example, I want to be able to write:

```
List<Player> fooPlayers = teamDao.findOneById(foo).getPlayers();
```

**EDIT**: If possible, I'd like to find a solution working with any spring data project

Comment: How to do that is simply explained in the [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.9.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#mongo.cross.store)

Comment: The @RelatedDocument annotation is nice, but it works only one-way. Besides, it works only with MongoDB (I'm going to edit my question to say I'd like a solution which works with any spring-data project)

Comment: There isn't a solution that works regardless of the technology. Your question was about Spring Data JPA and Spring Data MongoDB. That solution is clearly documented. The cross-store support is basically generic and could be extended to anything but that requires work on your part.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately your conundrum has no solution in spring data.

what may be a possibility is that you create an interface (DAO) class of your own. That DAO class would have implementations to to query both of your DBs. A very crude and short example would be

```
your DAO
{
    yourFind (id)
    {
        this would find in db2 and return a relevant list of objects
        findOneByID(id)
        get the player from the above retrieved list and query db1
        getPlayer(player)
    }
}
```

i hope this points you in the right direction