# Spring Data: fetching full entity from multiple data source with spring jpa

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, multiple-databases

I have 2 entities from 2 different data sources.

`Purchase` - data source A

`Merchant` - data source B

And they have one to one relationship.

I defined the `Purchase` entity as below.

I want when fetching purchase entity, it also takes into account the merchant from
the second datasource.

Is it possible?

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "purchase")
@Builder
public class Purchase extends BaseEntity {
    // ... other properties

    **// I want when fetching purchase entity, it also takes into account the merchant from
    // the second datasource.**
    // @Transient
    protected Merchant merchant;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37591503/spring-data-relationships-between-2-different-data-sources